# C# keyword "out" as an output parameter in the method TryParse()

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

**Hey Guys!**

I want to know, why I must use a *output parameter* in the *TryParse()* - method, because for me it is not clear why we use it.

For example:

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse("2", out number))
    Console.WriteLine("The parse worked!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The parse didn't work!");
}
```

Shorter:

```
int.TryParse("2", out int number)
```

I hope you can help me and that you can give me some great tips!

Comment: Um, because the second parameter of `int.TryParse` *is* an `out` parameter? It's really not clear what you're asking. Note that your second form is valid in C# 7.

Comment: Why? Because `TryParse` was defined with the second parameter as being an `out` parameter - in order to call it, you must use the `out` modifier on the passed in argument.

Comment: But for me it is not clear **why** you must use this parameter.

Comment: The short answer is because a function can only return one value. `TryParse` needs to tell you a) if it worked, and b) what the parsed value is. One solution to that problem would be to return an object with a `WasSuccessful` and `Value` property, the other is to use an `out` parameter

Comment: So what you want is not actually parse the string but rather to check if it is an integer or not.

Comment: @MattBurland this is a **pretty good definition** for it!  When I use the keyword *return* it jumps out of the method?

Comment: It looks like someone went through and downvoted every *answer* because they didn't like the *question*.

Comment: @ScottHannen I know that my questions may look stupid, but I am a new programmer and **I sometimes don't understand** some things.

Comment: @RafaelFarcher Your question isn't stupid and it doesn't look stupid. It's true that you could Google it and maybe find the answer easily. Someone can mark it as a duplicate or unclear if they want, and that's understandable. But when they accompany that with snarky, borderline sarcastic comments it suggests elitism and contempt, which I find offensive even when directed at someone else. Snarky doesn't help anyone, ever.

Comment: @RafaelFarcher BTW - That's why I answered the question. In this case I think it would have made sense to mark it as a duplicate. Moderators moderate. That's what they do, so if you ask a question that they feel is answered elsewhere they can moderate accordingly. That's not personal. Unless they're deliberately rude about it. Then it's sort of personal, like they're having a bad day or don't enjoy helping people anymore and decided to take it out on someone who just asked a simple question, and take it out some more on anyone who tries to help.

Comment: @ScottHannen thank you for your answers and I understand when this question is marked as duplicated and I found a kind of the same question. But the answers there **didn't fulfil my leak of information**.

Comment: @RafaelFarcher Don't forget to upvote if it helps. I already got a downvote just for answering it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the `out` keyword is necessary?

Usually when you call a method with parameters, the method gets it's own copy of those variables - a couple of bytes on the *stack* is reserved for the method. When the method reaches the end it releases all those bytes. Hence any value that was stored there is lost. The `out` keyword instructs the compiler to retain the value of that parameter so that the caller can use it. Internally it passes a reference to the original variable that is in the caller method, so any update is actually updating the caller's variable therefore it does not get lost.

As OP points out in comments. `out` is similar to the `ref` keyword, except that when using `ref` the method can ignore it, but `out` must be assigned a value before returning.

Comment: Like the keyword `ref`but the keyword `out` needs to get a value before a method ends. Is that right?

Comment: @RafaelFarcher That's right, I'll add that into the answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Without the `out` parameter, `TryParse` would *receive* the value of the integer but wouldn't be able to modify the value of the variable in the calling method. In this case

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse("2", out number))
```

the intent is not just to pass `number` to the `TryParse` method, but to modify the value of `number`. Without the `out` parameter the value of `number` would never change. The only use of the function would be to see if the number could be parsed, so the name of the function might as well be `CanParse`.

This behavior allows you to avoid evaluating the value to be parsed twice. Otherwise you might have to do something like this.

```
var s = "5";
int x;
if(int.CanParse(s)) //not a real function
{
    x = int.Parse(s);
}
```

You would really be parsing the string twice - once to see if it can be parsed as an `int`, and then again to get the parsed value.

A side effect is that we have to declare the `out` variable first, which is a small nuisance. With C# 7 you don't even need to do that. You can do this:

```
if(int.TryParse(out var x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `out` parameter because `TryParse` already returns a boolean as result, and therefore you cant return a value as well.

The actual `out` keyword simply passes a variable via reference, and all this means is that functions can assign values to that variable, rather than just using it's currently value.

I think this is what you were asking, but if you need actual clarification on something, let me know :)

Comment: In C#7 you can return more than one value. Since the OP included C#7 code in the question it might be nice to clarify how this does or doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Because as the method name `TryParse` means its trying to parse.
If you  supplied first parameter can not be parsed to an `int` type it will return you a `false` value and default value 0 in out parameter. 
As we can not predict whether the string can be parsed to int or not.. out parameter is useful.

Hope I answered.

Answer (score 0):

"Out" keyword check is basically used for Overflow checks. TryParse Method ensures that supplied Integer Value in your case "2" is outside boundary of Integer-32 bit equivalents( Something like Min and Max Value specified in Int32) Struct types.

I would say out keyword gives you hint whether conversion successfull from string "2" or any other values.

Typical values are Actual Value "2" is successfull and 0- Unsuccessfull. By doing this check we can ensure bounday conditions are met and should not end up in runtime overflow exceptions.

Comment: That is not what the `out` keyword does. That is what the `TryParse` method does.